# {NSDecimalNumber integerValue} behaving strangely in iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsdecimalnumber

OK team, this is weird. [NSDecimalNumber integerValue] is behaving strangely.

I'm sat at a breakpoint, trying to figure out why some parts of my app are broken in iOS8, and I'm looking at a variable called "timeSeconds". It appears like this in the Xcode Variables View:

```
_timeSeconds    (NSDecimalNumber *) 344.514533996581994496
```

But when I query it in the debugger, I see this:

```
(lldb) p [self.timeSeconds doubleValue]
(double) $14 = 344.51453399658192
(lldb) p [self.timeSeconds intValue]
(int) $15 = 344
(lldb) p [self.timeSeconds integerValue]
(NSInteger) $16 = -5
(lldb) p (NSInteger)[self.timeSeconds intValue]
(NSInteger) $17 = 344
```

See that "-5"? Can any of you beautiful people reproduce or explain that, before I file a radar?

Here's the SSCCE:

```
NSDecimalNumber *n = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"344.514533996581994496"];
NSLog(@"%@", n); // 344.514533996581994496
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[n intValue]); // 344
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[n integerValue]); // -5
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[n unsignedIntegerValue]); // 12
```

Thanks in advance!

Matthew

Comment: Matthew - what did you find? NSDecimalNumber on iOS 8 is causing huge problems in my live app!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result for **integerValue** is surprising, but from what I understand as documented:

**NSDecimalNumber** inherits from **NSNumber**. In the subclassing notes from **NSNumber** it is stated that 
"*... subclass must override the accessor method that corresponds to the declared type—for example, if your implementation of objCType returns “i”, you must override intValue ...*"

**objCType** is set to the inner pointer, so it should be the same as for **NSNumber**.

**NSDecimal** does not override **intergerValue**.
It does override **doubleValue**, so that should work fine.

The only thing that makes me wonder: it seems it does not override **intValue** either ...

Comment: I think you are definitely on the right track. I'd like to understand this a little bit better and if you do figure out about intValue, please post your answer. But I am going to go ahead and award the bounty because I think this is the right direction and I don't want the bounty to run out without awarding it to you.

Comment: This is a related question where there is a more specific case of an NSDecimal problem that is likely related to this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741233/ios-8-number-conversion-formatting-error-cannot-reproduce

Answer (score 2):

What a great bug! I just found myself tricked by it. So, just to conclude dogsgods answer:

Do NOT:

```
NSInteger x = [myDecimalNumber integerValue];
```

Instead, do THIS:

```
NSInteger x = (NSInteger)[myDecimalNumber doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `myDecimalNumber.intValue` instead of `integerValue`

Answer (score 0):

You can use use intValue or unsignedIntValue just fine, but *NOT* integerValue or unsignedIntegerValue. Here is a unit test that demonstrates the issue, showing that it's related to numbers requiring more than 64 bits of precision:

```
//
//  NSDecimalNumberBugTests.m
//
//  Created by Lane Roathe on 6/1/17.
//  For Quicken, Inc.
//

#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface NSDecimalNumberBugTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation NSDecimalNumberBugTests

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

- (void)tearDown {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testBug {
    // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
    NSDecimalNumber* decimalLength;
    NSUInteger interval;

    // Start with a number that requires 65+ bits

    // This FAILS (interval is zero)
    decimalLength = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.8446744073709551616"];
    interval = decimalLength.unsignedIntegerValue;
    XCTAssert(interval == 1);

    // This Works, interval is 1
    interval = decimalLength.unsignedIntValue;
    XCTAssert(interval == 1);

    // Now test with a number that fits in 64 bits

    // This WORKS (interval is 1)
    decimalLength = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.8446744073709551615"];
    interval = decimalLength.unsignedIntegerValue;
    XCTAssert(interval == 1);
}

@end
```