# Why is Swift .intValue is returning incorrect/weird values?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, decimal, nsdecimalnumber

I'm trying to convert a Decimal number which represents a dollar amount. Then I cast it into a NSDecimalNumber to apply .intValue transformation.

However I am getting weird behaviors. First it will give me an imprecise value when multiplying the value by 100. And when applying .intValue I get a completely unexpected number. Would appreciate your help!

```
//Issue
let dollars: Decimal = 106.99 * 100 // 10698.999999999997952
let cast = dollars as NSDecimalNumber // 10699
let int = cast.intValue //-7747


//No Problems here
let dollars2: Decimal = 106.98 * 100 // 10698
let cast2 = dollars2 as NSDecimalNumber // 10698
let int2 = cast2.intValue //10698
```

Comment: NSDecimalNumber has serious bugs, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/56036637/1187415, and the bug report at https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2980

Comment: Also observed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25705511/1187415.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try doing this

```
let dollars = "\(106.99 * 100)"
let cast = NSDecimalNumber(string: dollars)
let int = cast.intValue
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Decimal`'s `FloatLiteralType` is `Double`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal/1779898-init).

Trouble is, `106.99` can't be represented by `Double`. Just popping it into a `Decimal` is problematic:

```swift
Decimal(106.99) == 106.98999999999997952 // true
106.99 as Decimal * 100 // 10698.999999999997952
```

So, you've got to sanitize your `Double`s.

```swift
extension Decimal {
  init(dollarsAndCents: Double) {
    self = Self( (dollarsAndCents * 100).rounded() ) / 100
  }
}
```

```swift
extension Decimal {
  var dollarsAndCents: (dollars: Int, cents: Int) {
    (self * 100 as NSDecimalNumber).intValue
    .quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 100) as (Int, Int)
  }
}
```

```swift
Decimal(dollarsAndCents: 106.99).dollarsAndCents // (dollars: 106, cents: 99)
```

This is fine in practice because `Decimal` is for money. Sanitize and you'll never run into bugs.

Comment: This would explain rounding errors, but not why 10699 suddenly becomes -7747. As mentioned above, this is a *bug.*

Comment: Why cant 106.99 be represented by a Double?

Comment: @klmitchell2: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken. See for yourself in a playgorund, paste `let x = 106.99;  print(x / 100.0)`

Comment: @Gereon Heres an example, but I can correctly cast to double: 
`let x: Double = 106.99 let y: Double = x / 100.0 print(type(of: y)) //Double`

Comment: Casting isn't the issue here, it's the precise (or, in this case, imprecise) representation of values: `let x = 0.3; let x3 = 3.0 * x; print(0.9 - x3)`